# Why cant we close bounty questions?

Tags: discussion

i believe this [question](https://superuser.com/questions/490083/windows-xp-drag-and-drop-switch-focus-to-target/938879#938879) might be a duplicate of this [one](https://superuser.com/questions/18383/preventing-applications-from-stealing-focus),while i tried to flag it there was an error message stating that bounty questions cant be closed?

Can i flag it do moderator attention instead?